# Error: Parse Error: Invalid method encountered (ws)

Tags: node.js, ws

I've recently had an issue with the `ws` library in node.js, where i get the `HPE_INVALID_METHOD` error code. The entire error that is logged while using ws.on("error") is :

```
[Error: Parse Error: Invalid method encountered] {
  bytesParsed: 0,
  code: 'HPE_INVALID_METHOD',
  reason: 'Invalid method encountered',
  rawPacket: <Buffer 16 03 01 02 00 01 00 01 fc 03 03 f5 f7 10 84 a8 45 4e df b5 7b 88 09 f5 09 75 ec 28 09 57 08 f4 96 f6 52 96 2e 6d 03 c3 a8 72 bf 20 ad f7 ee 0a d0 f1 ... 467 more bytes>
}
```

I tried to find how to fix it, but I do not know how. Note that the error happens on connection, so I haven't manipulated the wss yet.